# Application synchronization in pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

How do I do application/object synchronization in pywinauto for my application? 
We moved for UFT to python+pywinauto. In UFT, there were random instances when our application under test used to be too busy to respond to actions or didn't respond immediately to an UI action like clicking a button due to some internal processing it was doing. We had set syncronization timeout default value to 60 seconds and UFT used to wait for the application to respond automatically and then perform the operation.
How do I handle such situation in pywinauto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default timeout in pywinauto is 5 sec. It can be changed globally (not recommended!):

```
from pywinauto.timings import Timings
Timings.window_find_timeout = 60
```

Or you can do explicit waiting while specified control appears or disappears. It's described in more details in the docs: [Waiting for Long Operations](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html).

Example:

```
app.MainWindow.menu_select('File->Open')
app.OpenDialog.wait('ready', timeout=10)
app.OpenDialog.Edit.set_text('file name')
app.OpenDialog.Open.click()
app.OpenDialog.wait_not('visible', timeout=30)
app.ChangedMainWindowTitle.wait('ready', timeout=60)
```

[EDIT] One more powerful method:

```
# wait until CPU usage is lower than 2.5%
app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=2.5)
```

It will wait until CPU usage goes down for this particular process (it's NOT system wide CPU load). See the docs for more detailed params of this method.

Comment: Yes, but the problem I am facing is that my application might stop responding for few seconds due a load that it might be processing for "any action" and  "anytime" (click, open window, set text, etc). Incase of UFT the global synchronization timeout kicks in anywhere and everywhere.  So I dont have code for anything specific in UFT.  In pywinauto, do we have any such global setting?

Comment: If I use global Timings.window_find_timeout = 60, and then inside by code if I use app.OpenDialog.wait_not('visible', timeout=10) then would it wait 10 seconds ?

Comment: `Timings.window_find_timeout` is global, but if you want to override it in `.wait_not('visible', timeout=10)` it will be 10 for this particular action. All other implicit or explicit waits will use 60. If you call just `.wait_not('visible')` the timeout is 60 again.

Comment: With global settings == 60 `app.OpenDialog.Open.click()` will also implicitly wait up to 60 sec. (or less if it's fast) while `app.OpenDialog.Open` appears on the screen.